# drupal ajax form

Tags: php, ajax, forms, drupal, drupal-7

What I want to do is: I want to render a form on a page with a view. This view has a list of 'notes' (=CT Note). When you fill in the form, the note is stored, the form is cleared, and the new note is added to the list. All without page refreshes.

I create a module new_note, and addes this function:

```
    function new_note_form($nodeid = NULL) {
        ctools_include('ajax');
        //  drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'custom_forms') . '/js/note_form.js');
        //dpm($nodeid);
        module_load_include('inc', 'node', 'node.pages');
        $form = node_add('note');
        $form['field_note_reference']['und']['#value'] = '2';
        $form['field_note_reference']['und']['#validated'] = 'TRUE';
        $form['field_note_reference']['#attributes']['class'][] = "hidden";
        $form['submit'] = array(
            '#type' => 'submit',
            '#value' => 'Submit',
            '#executes_submit_callback' => FALSE,
            '#ajax' => array(
                'callback' => 'ajax_note',
                'wrapper' => 'status',
            ),
        );
     $output= drupal_render($form);
        dpm($form);
        print $output;
    }

function ajax_note(&$form, &$form_state) {
    return 'test';
}
```

I use this function in a display suite block field, which is rendered above the note list. So far so good.

The only problem is, that when I submit the form, the ajax is not called, and the normal submit is done.

Can anyone help me out

@ Edit.

After what clive suggested I changed the code, and got the ajax working.

```
function new_notes_form($nodeid = NULL) {
    global $user;

    $node = (object) array(
                'uid' => $user->uid,
                'name' => (isset($user->name) ? $user->name : ''),
                'type' => 'note',
                'language' => LANGUAGE_NONE,
    );
    $form_state = array();
    $form_state['build_info']['args'] = array($node);
    form_load_include($form_state, 'inc', 'node', 'node.pages');
    $form = drupal_build_form('note_node_form', $form_state);
    $form['field_note_reference']['und']['#value'] = '2';
    $form['field_note_reference']['#attributes']['class'][] = "hidden";
    $form['submit'] = array(
        '#type' => 'button',
        '#value' => 'Submit',
        '#limit_validation_errors' => array(),
        '#ajax' => array(
            'callback' => 'ajax_note_replace',
            'wrapper' => 'status',
        ),
    );
    return $form;
}

function ajax_note_replace(&$form, &$form_state) {
    dpm("test");
    dpm($form);
    $output = '<h1>' . t('Hello World') . '</h1>';
    // $node = node_load('6');
    // $output .= drupal_render(node_view($node, $style = 'teaser', $options = array()));

    ctools_include('ajax');
    $commands = array();
    $commands[] = ajax_command_prepend(".view-content", $output);
    print ajax_render($commands); // this function exits.
    exit;
}
```

@Clive, can you help me out with the rest ? I want to save the node on callback (if valid?). In the ajax callback my node-id is null because it is not stored yet? how can I validate and save the node, otherwise set the not valid form items to red as normal.

Comment: Can you post the code for `advanced_form_callback()`?

Comment: Sorry had a wrong version, updated it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's likely to be because you're sidestepping Drupal's proper methods for creating forms so the AJAX preprocessing won't be performed. If you have a look at [`drupal_get_form()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--form.inc/function/drupal_get_form/7) (the function used pretty much exclusively to prepare a form in Drupal) you'll see it in turn calls [`drupal_build_form()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--form.inc/function/drupal_build_form/7) which is what you need to do:

```
function new_note_form($form, &$form_state, $nodeid = NULL) {
  $form_state['build_info']['args'] = array('note');
  $form = drupal_build_form('node_add', $form_state);

  $form['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'button',
    '#value' => 'Submit',
    '#limit_validation_errors' => array(),
    '#ajax' => array(
        'callback' => 'advanced_form_callback',
        'wrapper' => 'status',
    ),
  );

  return $form;
}

echo render(drupal_get_form('new_note_form'));
```

I've changed the element from type `submit` to `button` because I find it works much better when you want to do some ajax processing, removed `#executes_submit_callback`, and added `#limit_validation_errors` which will stop the form from otherwise validating (I think that's what you were trying to do by setting `#validated` to `TRUE` but I might be wrong).

Hope that helps, it's untested but should give you a good place to start.

Comment: Hmm, I get: Undefined index: node_add in drupal_retrieve_form()

Comment: Ah yes sorry, add `module_load_include('inc', 'node', 'node.pages');` at the top as you did in your original function. Also you should return a form element from your AJAX callback, or an ajax command built up using the [AJAX functions](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--ajax.inc/group/ajax)

Comment: could you help me out with validating and saving the node please ?

Comment: The form should go through the normal validate/submit handlers and the node should be validated and saved as normal. If not you might need to re-attach some handlers or something. You might be best off posting another question for that, it'll be difficult to discuss it in the comments. I'll keep me eye out in case you do and try to help :)

Comment: Ok, anyway thank you very very much allready. At the moment, i was thinking: why do I need such heavy code, so I am building a simpeler form :)

Comment: Good idea, if you can do without including the node edit form it'll save you a lot of headaches. Then you just need to use the `node_save()` function in your submit handler to save the node to the database and you're good to go

Comment: Correct, all is working now, I can add Notes to my other content types. Accept from the fact that if you have a very long form, which would make recreating it a pain, are there other reasons to not create a custom form to create a Node ?

Comment: I suppose you lose the validation that's provided for custom fields, but if you provide that validation yourself anyway then no I can't think of any good reason not to create a custom form. Even then you could use [`field_attach_form()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--field--field.attach.inc/function/field_attach_form/7) to attach those custom fields to the form so it's really your decision as the programmer how you want to implement it. That's just my opinion but it's served me pretty well with Drupal :)

Comment: One last question, In my callback function, how can I check if the form is valid ? How c an I add errors to the fields ? BTW you are a live saver

Comment: Search for form_set_error() on google, you use it like: form_set_error("field_name", "error message");

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6063/discussion-between-nealv-and-clive)